# How To Stop display push notification while open app in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
package com.test.android

import android.app.*
import android.app.Notification.*
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_profile.*


class AlarmBroadcastReceiver2: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        showNotification(context)

    }
    internal fun showNotification(context: Context) {
        val CHANNEL_ID = "1"// The id of the channel.
        val name = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)// The user-visible name of the channel.
        val mBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder
        val notificationIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        val bundle = Bundle()
        notificationIntent.putExtras(bundle)
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP )

        val contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
           context,
            1,
            notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )



        val mNotificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26)
        {

            val mChannel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                name,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )



            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
            mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLights(Color.RED, 300, 300)
                .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setDefaults(DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                //.setContentTitle("Selamat Pagi Jangan Lupa Untuk Absensi ")
                .setStyle(
                    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()

                        // Provide the bitmap to be used as the payload for the BigPicture notification.
                        .bigPicture(
                            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                context.resources,
                                R.drawable.absence2_2
                            )
                        )

                        // Override the large icon when the big notification is shown.
                        .bigLargeIcon(
                            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                context.resources,
                                R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round
                            )
                        )


                        // Overrides ContentTitle in the big form of the template.
                        .setBigContentTitle("Selamat Sore Jangan Lupa Untuk Absensi ")


                        // Set the first line of text after the detail section in the big form of the template.
                        .setSummaryText("Mohon melakukan absensi sore ini,Terima kasih")

                )

        }
        else
        {
            mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                //.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
        }
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setDefaults(DEFAULT_ALL)
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
        val note = mBuilder.build()
        //mBuilder.setContentText("Yth Kepada Seluruh Karyawan dimohon untuk melakukan absensi di pagi ini,Terima Kasih")
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build())

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
        } else {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
        }




    }


}




//notif4 16.00 evening
val _intent2 = Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver2::class.java)
val pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, _intent2, 0)
val alarmManager2 = this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
alarmManager2.cancel(pendingIntent2)
val calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar2.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis())
calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16)
calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
calendar2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
//alarmManager2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar2.getTimeInMillis() /1000, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent2)
//alarmManager2.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar2.getTimeInMillis()/1000 ,  pendingIntent2)
//alarmManager2.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar2.getTimeInMillis()/1000 ,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pendingIntent2)
alarmManager2.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar2.getTimeInMillis() ,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pendingIntent2)
```

I'm new to android development... trying to build application which send notification at specific time daily.First time if I tap on notification it opens application and notification doesn't come again. But after that if I open application it shows notification again.. how to stop showing it again? but show only at particular time?

Comment: Need help thank u, jazakumullah khairan

Comment: just cancel the notification by its id like this  NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); notificationManager.cancel(1);

Comment: syukron katsiron, i will try sir :)

Comment: not working sir why?

Comment: val pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, _intent2, 0)
  val alarmManager2 = this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
  alarmManager2.cancel(pendingIntent2)  i added 1 but error because this code in mainactivity

Comment: please full code sir  you can copy paste my code above

Comment: mNotificationManager.cancel(id)
error in code sir

Comment: i am confuse ,please help with my code above

Comment: I try put mNotificationManager.cancel(1) in receiver make notification not show why?